# Jquery conflict click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using jquery for chat heads, in corner of chat heads there are "X" sign to remove chat head, when click on "X" which is `button` it also activates chat head div.. 
structure of chat head is like

```
<div class="name_right">

<button class="close_chat_in">X</button>

</div>
```

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vve3gp7q/1/), Please have a look and suggest me the right way to perform such action. 
while this works fine for static elements but when i load elements by ajax or add element by append it doesn't work. have a look on fiddle to clear the point.

Thanks

Comment: you could stop the propagation of the event, when the event for .close_chat_in is invoked. Use `return false;` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vve3gp7q/3/). You need to stop the propagation of events after X is clicked.

Close chat JS function:

```
$("body").on("click", ".close_chat_in", function (ev) {
        $(this).parent(".name_right").remove();
        alert("i am suppose to remove this chat head");
        $('body').append("<div class='name_right'><span/n/ style='border-radius:100%;margin:0px;padding:0px;color:black;background:#F78F1E;'></span>\n\<button class='close_chat_in' id=''>&nbsp;X&nbsp;</button></div>");
        ev.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add more code to your question, however, change:

```
$("body").on("click", ".close_chat_in", function () {
```

To

```
$("body div.name_right").on("click", ".close_chat_in", function () {
```

This just moves the listener to within your div, instead of within the whole body and thus it won't fire the other listener at the same time.